# Setting a value XmlConfig

Tags: wix

Hi I am trying to change a value setting in a config file using the following:

```
    <Component Id="Enable32BitAppPoolComponent" Guid="*" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION">
        <CreateFolder/>
        <util:XmlConfig Id="Enable32BitAppPool" Node="value"
                      ElementPath="//configuration/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add[\[]@name='DefaultAppPool'[\]]/@enable32BitAppOnWin64"
                      File="[inetsrv]\config\applicationHost.config"
                      Value="true" On="install"/>
    </Component>
```

This code does not change the value in the `applicationHost.config` file. I tried adding the `action="create"` but I then got the error during the setup that it could not open the XML file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's more convenient to use XmlFile elements to modify attribute values:

```
<Component Id="Enable32BitAppPoolComponent" Guid="*" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION">
<CreateFolder/>
<util:XmlFile Id="Enable32BitAppPool" 
    Action="setValue"
    Name="enable32BitAppOnWin64" 
    ElementPath="//configuration/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add[\[]@name='DefaultAppPool'[\]]" 
    File="[inetsrv]\config\applicationHost.config" 
    PreserveModifiedDate="yes"
    SelectionLanguage="XPath" 
    Sequence="INSERTCORRECTSEQUENCENUMBERHERE"
    Value="true" />
</Component>
```

You have to correctly assign the Sequence number in the snippet above.

The Sequence attribute is also missing in your XmlConfig element, so that might be a problem with your code. Another problem is the definition of the `ElementPath` attribute. Adding `@enable32BitAppOnWin64` to it is wrong. The `ElementPath` attribute locates the element you want to change, in your case the `add` element which has the `name` attribute of `DefaultAppPool`. In that element you want to change the value of an attribute. You specify the attribute by its name. For that purpose you have to add the `name` attribute to your `XmlConfig` element. In combination with the `Node` attribute set to `value` the attribute definition is complete. The `Action` attribute of the XmlConfig element has to be set to `create`. The `VerifyPath` attribute of the XmlConfig element is used to determine if the Node shall be added or modified.

The correct version of your XmlConfig element should look like this:

```
<Component Id="Enable32BitAppPoolComponent" Guid="*" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION">
    <CreateFolder/>
    <util:XmlConfig
    Id="Enable32BitAppPool"
    Action="create" 
    Node="value"
    ElementPath="//configuration/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add[\[]@name='DefaultAppPool'[\]]"
    File="[inetsrv]\config\applicationHost.config"
    Name="enable32BitAppOnWin64"
    Value="true"
    On="install"/>
</Component>
```

If your installer tells you it cannot open the XML File, then you have to check if the `File` attribute's value is correct. Maybe you need to change it to something like `"[INSTALLFOLDER]\config\applicationHost.config"` or whatever you set the `Id` attribute of your installation directory to. The installer log should provide you with the information which file could not be opened.

Comment: There are two ElementPath in you util:XmlConfig